# Change name of mongoid relations (embeds_...,belongs_to,has_...)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

When you have a relation such as `embeds_many :album_items` which relates to the `AlbumItem` model. How can I have it stored in just `items`. I tried `embeds_many :album_items, :as => :items` and `embeds_many :items, :class_name => AlbumItem`. Neither worked.

How can I go about renaming the relation?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work(assuming your parent model name is `Album`)?

In Album:

```
embeds_many :items, :class_name => "AlbumItem", :inverse_of => :album
```

and in AlbumItem:

```
embedded_in :album, :class_name => "Album", :inverse_of => :items
```

Comment: It gives me an obscure error

    >> a = Album.create
    NoMethodError: undefined method `sub' for AlbumItem:Class
      from /Users/tal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mongoid-2.4.4/lib/mongoid/relations/metadata.rb:117:in `class_name'

Comment: Updated to use string not pure class for :class_name.